# babel enable import of each dir from root without relative

Tags: babeljs

My root dir structure is like so:

- src
- utils
- types
- clients
- package.json
- etc.

my current babel config i run is like:

```
{
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-typescript', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-flow'],
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import', '@babel/transform-runtime'],
    env: {
      build: {
        ignore: ['**/*.spec.tsx', '**/*.spec.ts', '**/*.stories.tsx']
      }
    },
    ignore: ['node_modules']
  }
```

How do I allow various `/src` files directly imports from root. eg.

```
import { handyFunction } from 'utils'
import { api } from 'clients'
```

as opposed to doing this relatively:

```
import { handyFunction } from '../../../utils'
import { api } from '../../../clients'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use babel plugin module resolver as mentioned here https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver.